# Deleting n elements of a List

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I am writing a program that does some list manipulations in scheme (R5RS). 
I am trying to create a procedure that will remove `n` items at index `i` of a list `L`.
I have written procedures that return all but the first `n` items in `L` and a procedure that returns only the first `n` elements of `L`.
I was able to write a procedure that removes the `ith` item of `L` but cannot figure out how to remove `n` items. This is my remove procedure:

```
(define (remove L i)
  (cond ((null? L)'())
        ((= i 0) (cdr L))
        (else (cons (car L) (remove (cdr L) (- i 1))))))

`(remove '(1 2 3 4 5) 2)` -> (1 2 4 5)
```

I am struggling to come up with a procedure `(remove L i n)` that will do the following:

`(remove '(1 2 3 4 5) 2 2) -> (1 2 5)`

Comment: Hint: you can define it in terms of the two other functions you wrote and `append`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (remove L i count)
  (append
   (take L i)
   (if (< (length (list-tail L i)) count)
       (list-tail L i)
       (list-tail L (+ i count)))))
```

This function's meaning should be this:
1. Take first i items.
2. From i, check if have enough count item
   if have, ignore them, take the rest.
   if not, take the rest.
Append 1 and 2 steps's items.

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you're doing and why the OP's code does/doesn't work. Don't just post code. Thank you!

Comment: I add some explanation, and I think your code's main problem is you overthinking this function and you have not get the code style of the LISP.

Comment: I'm not the questioner. If you have anything to say to him, put it as a comment on his question. (:

Comment: :) And I have to say, you can tell your friend: don't use stackoverflow to complete homework, think by yourself first.